# How to use Command Grep inside a script

Tags: variables, unix, command

I'm using this inside a script:

```
VAR=$(grep -c mac myfile.tmp)
echo $VAR
```

the result is 0 when I run the script. But if I run the command in command line it returns the real value that is 1.

Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: if windows was involved in creating script or any filles, use `dos2unix file1 file2 file...n` Good luck.

Comment: Is your script in the same location as `myfile.tmp`?

Comment: Your script is correct, we'd need to see myfile.tmp to know what you're grepping for. I made a simple script like `#!/bin/sh
VAR=$(grep -c test_string ~/file_containing_test_string)
echo $VAR` and it works fine